# Electron: Loading a JS file instead of an HTML file into a BrowserWindow

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to integrate an existing redux app into ElectronJS.

The boilerplate template has following code in `main.js`

```js
mainWindow.maximize() 
// and load the index.html of the app.
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
```

I would like to change the `index.html` to my React app's `index.js` file.

Answer (score 2):

In Electron, you would still call `mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')`.

Even though you're writing React code for your app's view, all React apps still need to call [ReactDOM.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) at some point to attach your app to some HTML file's DOM.

Assuming your `index.js` file is the one that calls `ReactDOM.render()`, what you would need to do is not too different from a normal React web-app.

```js
// main.js
// ...
mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
// ...
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!-- ... -->
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="../path/to/index.js"></script>
</body>
<!-- ... -->
```

```js
// index.js

// ...
const app = <MyRootAppComponent/>
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue like this for my fullstack web application (local) which includes nodejs, express, ejs, mongo, etc...

step 1: change your web app main js file in package.json (mine server.js)

```
"main": "server.js",
```

to

```
"main": "desktop.js", // or what you want
```

step 2: convert your app main js file, server.js, main.js, app.js or whatever.js to a module.

from

```js
const startServer = async function () {
...
}
startServer();
```

to

```js
const startServer = async function () {
...
}
//startServer();
module.export = startServer;
```

step 3: create desktop.js file in app directory.

[image]

step 4: create your electron app in desktop.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        // window options
        title: 'Garaj Portal',
    });
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

step 5: Main idea is that run your server.js file before load anything.
After that just load url like http:localhost:3000

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const startServer = require('./server');

async function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
       ...
    });

    await startServer();
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:27027')
}
```